# Finding the first word that browsers will classify as overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, typography

I'm looking to build a page that has no scrolling, and will recognize where the main div's contents overflow.  The code will remember that point and construct a separate page that starts at that word or element.

I've spent a few hours fiddling, and here's the approaches that past questions employ:

*1.  Clone the div, incrementally strip words out until the clone's height/width becomes less than the original's.*
Too slow.  I suppose I could speed it up by exponentially stripping words and then slowly filling it back up--running past the target then backtracking slowly till I hit it exactly--but the approach itself seems kind of brute force.

*2.  Do the math on the div's dimensions, calculate out how many ems will fit horizontally and vertically.*
Would be good if all contents were uniform text, ala a book, but I'm expecting to deal with headlines and images and whatnot, which throws a monkey wrench in this one.  Also complicated by browsers' different default font preferences (100%?  144%?)

*3.  Render items as tokens, stop when the element in question (i.e. one character) is no longer visible to the user onscreen.*
This would be my preferred approach, since it'd just involve some sort of isVisible() check on rendered elements.  I don't know if it's consistent with how browsers opt to render, though.

Any recommendations on how this might get done?  Or are browsers designed to render the whole page length before deciding whether a scrollbar is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cloning the div, you could just have an `overflow:hidden` div and set `div.scrollTop += div.height` each time you need to advance a 'page'.  (Even though the browser will show no scrollbar, you can still programmatically cause the div to scroll.)

This way, you let the browser handle what it's *designed* to do (flow of content).

Here's a snippet that will automatically advance through the pages:  [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/uWTFC/)

```
var div = $('#pages'), h = div.height(), len = div[0].scrollHeight, p = $('#p');
setInterval(function() {
   var top = div[0].scrollTop += h;
   if (top >= len) top = div[0].scrollTop = 0;
   p.text(Math.floor(top/h)+1 + '/' + Math.ceil(len/h)); // Show 'page' number
}, 1000);
```

You could also do some fiddling to make sure that a 'page' does not start in the middle of a block-level element if you don't want (for example) headlines sliced in half.  Unfortunately, it will be much harder (perhaps impossible) to ensure that a line of text isn't sliced in half.

Comment: Against the split-lines you could add some (css-pseudo-)elements in the foreground top and bottom of #pages, with with vertical linear gradient. Makes it really good-looking :-)

Comment: Didn't know that existed.  Thanks!  In order to make each snippet feel like its own page, I'll need a way of detecting whether a block-level element forces an overflow.  Right now clone-and-compare is still all I have...is there a browser function that will show when something's tripping overflow?

Comment: @midnightinfour: Loop through each element in the container, and if it is a block-level element `$('#pages *').each(function() { $(this).css('display') == 'block' });`, then add `this.offsetTop` to an array.  Use that array to know what pixels to snap to when setting `scrollTop` so that a block-level element always starts at the top.